# How to explode multiple columns (which are dictionaries with the same key) of a pyspark dataframe into rows

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, explode

The data frame has multiple columns in dictionary format - which have the same key.
How can I explode them into rows without having to use any joins keeping the key from any of the columns?

[The schema of the data frame is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSFI5.png)
The columns that need to be exploded are pct_ci_tr, pct_ci_rn, pct_ci_ttv and pct_ci_comm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(
    "s__",
    F.expr("""
        stack(
            4,
            "pct_ci_tr",
            pct_ci_tr,
            "pct_ci_rn",
            pct_ci_rn,
            "pct_ci_ttv",
            pct_ci_ttv,
            "pct_ci_comm",
            pct_ci_comm,
        ) as (lib, map_values)"""
    ),
).select("s__", "lib", F.explode(F.col("map_values")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Steven, but I am getting a java heap space error with this. I think the union operation is creating too many stages /tasks. Adjusting spark driver memory or adjusting partitions is not helping either. I am out of ideas to achieve the desired result without having to unionize or join.

Comment: @RoopanjaliJasrotia See my updated version